# unable to use sessions in asp.net core "No service for ISession" Registered

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

i have followed official website docs to configure Session State
here is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
        });
        services.AddMvc();
    }
```

and this is Configure:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        app.UseSession();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

however i get this error when trying to inject `ISession`into views

> InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.ISession' has been registered.

as requested in comments i add view code also:

```
@inject ISession Session
```

nothing special.

Comment: please add your view code as well.

Comment: @ahmar added view code, i solved the problem by using Context Property any way. but still would like to know how to inject it manually.

Answer (score 4):

you should register IHttpContextAccessor in your Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

And then you can inject it into your view:

```
@inject Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor
@{
    var session = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try use IHttpContextAccessor

```
@inject Microsoft​.AspNetCore​.Http.IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

@if(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session ...)
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but did not work. now getting same error for IHttpContextAccessor .